# Make and acces a local variable in Assembly for a print function

Tags: assembly, local-variables, 8051

I am learning assembly and I am getting the hang of it. But there is this one thing I cannot get to work.

In order to print information on a display over the serial bus, I made a print function.

In C I wrote my own print function which was called like `print("hello world");`
The print function was a simple while loop which used a pointer to set bytes in the Tx buffer. The uController used code memory for the string rather than the xdata memory AND code memory.

In assembly I am now attempting to make something similar. I believe that my print function works correctly (does it?). I believe that the problem lies with the variable, it's scope and the place I am declaring/initialize the string.

In combination with the print function I use a set position function which used r6 and r7 and a specific instruction byte to set the write position for the display.

```
setposa  mov   a,#setapos     ;set position x-y
         lcall chrout
         mov   a,r6         ;x position
         lcall chrout
         mov   a,r7         ;y position
         lcall chrout
         ret 



print       lcall setposa   
print1      movx a, @dptr   ; put the character in a (used by chrout)
            jz print2       ; if charac is not /0, print it else jump to end
            lcall chrout
            inc dptr
            jmp print1
print2      ret
```

I am calling the print function with these lines:

```
;tab_bas   db 'this is a string',0  ; SHOULD NOT BE HERE?, DOES NOT WORK!! send tons of data to display resulting in a crash  I believe this line of code never runs  
s08p44    clr stepkey           ; clear this bit for re-use
tab_bas   db 'this is a string',0   ;having it here seems not to do anything, nothing happens   
          mov r6,#5
          mov r7,#6             ; set position for the text
          mov dptr, #tab_bas    ; set datapointer at text to print
          call print            ; print the text at desired position
          jmp s08p38            ; jump to ret instruction
```

I want to make a local string variable, set x and y using r6 and r7 and than print the local string variable. The chrout function is not mine and is proven to work. It puts the content of A in the Tx buffer and sets the transmitt flag if the buffer is empty.

I do not yet understand the scope of variables well enough to understand why it is not working. I also tried to declare the string on a place where all other variables are stored but that also does not work.

How can I get this to work?

Also: the string is to be put in xdata memory as ram is limited. But I'd prefer to use code memory. Can this be done in a relative easy way?

Additional information: I am programming a 8051 softcore and I am using the AVOCET A51 assembler.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was using the movc instruction instead of movx inside the print function to correctly let the data pointer point at the table (the single string)

```
print       lcall setposa
print1      clr a
            movc a,@ a + dptr       ; set datapointer at text to print
            jz print2       ; if charac is not /0, print it else jump to end
            lcall chrout
            inc dptr
            jmp print1
print2      ret
```